# OpenCL channels dynamic indexing

Tags: opencl, matrix-multiplication, channel

I want to implement a systolic structure for matrix multiplication. My objective is to use a single kernel for every Processing Element so I will execute the same kernel from the host part multiple times.

To communicate between kernels I would like to use channels or pipes. The problem is that "channels extension does not support dynamic indexing into arrays of channel IDs". The number of kernels will depend on the size of the matrix so I will need some method to connect the channels to the corresponding kernels automatically.

Summarizing, I am looking for a method to create this functionality:

```
channel float c0[32];

__kernel void producer (__global float * data_in){
    for(int i=0; i<32; i++){
        write_channel_altera(c0[i],data_in[i]);
    }
}

__kernel void consumer (__global float * ret_buf){
    for(int i=0; i<32; i++){
        ret_buf[i]=read_channel_altera(c0[i]);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

OpenCL channels (Intel FPGA extension) do not support "true" dynamic
indexing, but you can work around this limitation in most cases by
using `switch` or `#pragma unroll` approach:

`switch` approach is described in [Intel FPGA SDK for OpenCL Programming Guide](https://www.altera.com/documentation/mwh1391807965224.html#mwh1391806062355):

```
channel int ch[WORKGROUP_SIZE];

__kernel void consumer() {
    int gid = get_global_id(0);
    int value;

    switch(gid)
    {
        case 0: value = read_channel_intel(ch[0]); break;
        case 1: value = read_channel_intel(ch[1]); break;
        case 2: value = read_channel_intel(ch[2]); break;
        case 3: value = read_channel_intel(ch[3]); break;
        //statements

        case WORKGROUP_SIZE-1:read_channel_intel(ch[WORKGROUP_SIZE-1]); break;
    }
}
```

You can also use `#pragma unroll` if you have a loop over channels:

```
__kernel void consumer() {
    int values[WORKGROUP_SIZE]
    #pragma unroll
    for (int i = 0; i < WORKGROUP_SIZE; ++i) {
        values[i] = read_channel_intel(ch[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I think these solutions will work if I know the exact amount of channels and how they will be connected before compiling the kernel. In my case I would like a single kernel with a channel to connect to others. My idea is to have an undefined number of concurrent executions of this kernel and configure the connection of the channels from the host.

Comment: I think you can follow the `switch` approach and modify it to fit for your use case, though it may not super handy.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, we need to know how many channels we would require at the maximum much before compiling the program for the board, as we cannot program the FPGA like the way we do for other computing system and allocate resources on the go. Once we know the maximum number (atleast) we can use

#pragma unroll

before we start the loop for reading/writing the channels